# Fast Tetrahedralization Algorithm

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, tetrahedra

I have a concave volume and would like to break it into tetrahedra as quickly as possible. I am not too concerned about the quality of the output and I don't need a Delaunay tetrahedralization. (Specifically, I'm not looking for tetgen, or similar projects, which generates high quality Delaunay tetrahedralization for engineering applications. I want fast)

What is a fast, if not so high quality, algorithm I could use?

Comment: i'm curious why don't you care about accuracy.

Comment: I would like the tetrahedralization to match the original volume well, but I'm not concern about other measures of quality. For example I wouldn't mind if I had long thin tetrahedra. In fact matching the original volume exactly isn't essential. I will feed the tetrahedra to another algorithm that computes an approximate convex decomposition. This algorithm will deform (expand) the volume further

Comment: In packages like tetgen, this is not improving the quality of the tetrahedra that is the most difficult part. The most complicated part of the algorithm is the one that computes the initial terahedralization constrained by the surface. If you do not care about quality, then you can simply switch off the refinement in tetgen, and you will get an (ugly) tetrahedralization of the initial shape (I do not think that a simpler algorithm exists).